# WordPress hook for changing excerpt content when excerpt not set

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

Title says pretty much all of it. I need a filter that I can use to change excerpt content for those posts that have no excerpt set.

Now, I've tried both `the_excerpt` and `get_the_excerpt`, they both pass one parameter, and in both cases said parameter is empty string.

That said, I will need to hook onto a filter that has access to the auto-generated except, and lets me change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (untested)?

```
function my_filter_the_excerpt( $excerpt ) {

    global $post;

    if( empty( $post->post_excerpt ) ) {
        // Excerpt is auto-generated
        $excerpt = 'Something else...';
    }
    return $excerpt;

}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'my_filter_the_excerpt' );
```